# Why do I get an error when submitting to OData Edm.Decimal type?

Tags: javascript, json, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to submit some JSON to an OData service.  According to the $metadata, it expects this type:

```
<Property Name="curClaimValue" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="true" Precision="19" Scale="4"/>
```

This is part of my JSON:

..."curClaimValue":654321...

And this is the error message:

Error processing request stream. Error encountered in converting the value from request payload for property 'curClaimValue' to type 'Decimal', which is the property's expected type.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems I have to wrap the number in quotes.